# date_select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have an issue,
when i post the date in date_select it post the today's date, although i select the future date but it keeps giving me the current date.

<%= form.date_select :starts_at %>

does anyone help me out...
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your model.

Are some attributes attr_accessible while this isn't? Is it attr_protected?